# how to combining duplicate rows into unique row keeping value fields?

Tags: sql, duplicates, row, unique, rows

I have an unique table with 2 rows. The first column is "word" and second row is "definition", like this:

[table]

word | definition

```
buy | verb
car | noun
car | singular
car | countable
girl| noun
girl| singular
girl| countable
boy | noun
boy | singular
dog | noun
reds| adjective
reds| plural
```

and i need to delete duplicate entries (rows) and put the definitions in the same row but in different columns:

[newtable]

```
buy | verb
car | noun | singular | countable
girl| noun | singular | countable
boy | noun | singular
dog | noun
reds| adjective | plural
```

it seems easy, but i'm a begginer and need to do it with sql query. Can you help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Which **RDBMS** you are using?

Comment: MySQL 5.0 (and phpMyAdmin)

Comment: is this what you need http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/335c8/2

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group_Concat` Function.

```
select word,group_concat(definition) As 'definition'
from crostab 
group by word
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/335c8/3)

Comment: OUPS...i think that i tried to ask a question using single example, but i think that there's more complicated. That's the real table:

Comment: @user3182062 - Updated check now

Answer (score 0):

[table]

```
word    |   definition

abeyar  |   VaVeVhVjVkVmVpVrVtGa
abeya   |   SfGaYs
abeyera |   SfGaYs
abeyerin    |   SmGaYs
abeyerín    |   SmGaYs
abeyéru |   AaApGaYs
abeyéru |   Zz
abeyéru |   DdRr
abeyéru |   YyGgKk
abeyéru |   WwSs
abeyéru |   XxCc
abeyéru |   AaApGaYs
abeyerucu   |   SmGaYs
abeyeru |   SaGaYs
abeyeru |   Xxxxxx
abeyeru |   SmGaYs
abeyonar    |   VaVeVhVjVkVmVpVrVtGa
abeyón  |   SmGaYs
abeyota |   SfGaYs
```

And this is what i need to order. (you can see "abeyéru" has 7 rows). Each word can have 1 to 10 different deffinitions.

```
word    |   definition


abeyar  |   VaVeVhVjVkVmVpVrVtGa
abeya   |   SfGaYs
abeyera |   SfGaYs
abeyerin    |   SmGaYs
abeyerín    |   SmGaYs
abeyéru |   AaApGaYs,Zz,DdRr,YyGgKk,WwSs,XxCc,AaApGaYs
abeyerucu   |   SmGaYs
abeyeru |   SaGaYs,Xxxxxx,SmGaYs
```